# Apache Jena resultset not preserving order from the SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, jena

I am executing a SPARQL query in my java application and I expect the resultset to preserve the order provided in the SPARQL query.
The query returns ordered results when run in GraphDb editor, but when using Apache Jena, it does not return results in the expected order.
Observed that this may be related to the union joins in the SPARQL query, but not sure if that's the case.

Has anyone else seen this happen and know how to solve this.

Thank you!

Comment: can you show the SPARQL query please? and also the code you#re running

Comment: Maybe it is due to indexing. Without "ORDER BY", the order will be influenced by how its stored internally. Hash-based structures and internal ids will cause different orders across different systems.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your query contains an explicit [`ORDER BY`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#modOrderBy) clause there is no guarantee of result ordering.  The specification even calls this out in places e.g. [Section 15.4 OFFSET](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#modOffset) says the following:

> Using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to select different subsets of the query solutions will not be useful unless the order is made predictable by using `ORDER BY`.

Queries without the `ORDER BY` clause **may** consistently return results using a specific backend implementation but you **should not** rely on this behaviour.  At best this will give you different results in different implementations.  At worse results ordering could change when you upgrade your backend due to internal implementation/optimization changes in the underlying implementation.

If you want predictable result ordering you **MUST** provide an `ORDER BY` clause in your queries.

Comment: Thank you @RobV. The SPARQL query has an ORDER BY clause. It returns results in the expected order in GraphDB editor, but fails to render ordered results when using Apache Jena.

Comment: @Maddy Then you really need to follow the advice given in the comments on your question.  If you don't show your query and some sample data we can only guess at what's wrong, please edit your question to show those.  Your question needs to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) otherwise all we can do is speculate